# delete letter in the output linux

Tags: linux, shell, output

I have the text below as output in linux:

```
    service {'name': 'services'}
    enable yes
    frequency 7200
    service {'name': 'files'}
    enable yes
    frequency 6000
    none
```

Im looking the way to convert the output in something like:

```
services yes 7200
files yes 6000
```

Im using the next command:

```
| xargs -n 7 | awk '{print $3 " / " $5" / " $7}'
```

But as output im having:

```
services} / yes / 7200
files} / yes / 6000
```

Anyway to delete that }, or get the last output without this character?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're ok with removing any and all '}'s, the easiest thing to do is use translate:

```
| xargs -n 7 | awk '{print $3 " / " $5" / " $7}'| tr -d '{'
```

tr -d will delete every instance of '{'

Answer (score 2):

If you set the field separator to a run of anything but letters and numbers, it simplifies the parsing:

```
awk -F'[^a-z0-9]+' '
    /service/ {printf "%s ", $3}
    /enable/ {printf "%s ", $2}
    /frequency/ {print $2}
' /tmp/test-data
```

Output:

```
services yes 7200
files yes 6000
```